# Converting between symbols and strings

Tags: ruby

**I was asked this question:**

> We have an array of strings we'd like to later use as hash keys, but we'd rather they be symbols.
>
> 1. Create a new variable, `symbols`, and store an empty array in it.
> 2. Use `.each` to iterate over the `strings` array.
> 3. For each `s` in `strings`, use `.to_sym` to convert `s` to a symbol and use `.push` to add that new symbol to `symbols`.
> 4. Print the `symbols` array.

**The correct answer given was this:**

```
strings.each do |s|
  symbols.push(s.to_sym)
end 

print symbols
```

**I did it like this:**

```
strings.each do |string|
  if strings.include? "s"
    strings.gsub! (/s/, .to_sym)
  end
  symbols.push (string)
end

print symbols
```

The code didn't work. I'm trying to get help in that regards.

Comment: `s` is a variable defined in the cited question. Don't write that in the main body of question even before citing that question, as if it were an established fact that `s` is used to represent each string in an array called `strings`.

Answer (score 4):

As @tadman mentions, the question is not about `gsub` at all, but rather about iterating over an array and applying an operation to each element to create a new array.

The "correct" answer you show in your question will work, but a more typical Ruby solution would be to use `map`, like this:

```
>> strings = ["cat", "deer", "mouse"]
>> symbols = strings.map { |s| s.to_sym }
#> [:cat, :deer, :mouse]
```

Anytime you see this pattern, where a single method is called on the block variable, you can use an even more concise shorthand like this:

```
>> symbols = strings.map(&:to_sym)
#> [:cat, :deer, :mouse]
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `&` is not only about “a single method called on the block variable” it’s more general approach of converting anything to _proc_ and passing the result to the receiver _as block_, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5].detect(&3.method(:==))`. In the aforementioned case it works because of [`Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is "if the string *contains* a letter *s*" not "for each string (*s*) in the array...". It means they're hinting at using the variable `s` to represent each entry as you loop.

The problem is phrased using classic mathematical speak, like "for each person *P* in the population *O*... where *O* represents the set of all people living in city *C*..."

The reason the code doesn't work is because of this line:

```
strings.gsub! (/s/, .to_sym)
```

That's not valid Ruby. The `.to_sym` method *must* operate on something, it doesn't work in isolation. Additionally, `strings` is an array, it's not actually a string. In your loop `string` represents an individual entry. It should be *more like* this:

```
string.gsub!(/s/, string.to_sym)
```

Yet that's still not right because you can't have symbols inside of strings. An object is either a string *or* a symbol, not both.

The answer below is correct because it pushes a symbol value in and no `gsub` is required.